# Representation of multifield nested lists?

Tags: lists

By multifield I mean a list item having multiple kind of sublists, separated by some indicator like the grey blocks in the example below. The reason behind this may be an IF-THEN relationship between the statements in the sublists.

The question is what layout provides the best visual clues to determine at a glance the relationship of items. (In the example the second separator in a block is not distinct from the first so it is hard to tell the boundaries of a block)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use bigger padding, so that nested items are more visible, like in [this Accordion example](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/accordion/basic-usage)?

Answer (score 1):

Next to the padding, you could (should) also use another shade of grey (or another color) to emphasize the highest level of a thread.
This visually really helps to determine the highest (and most important) entry.